# Magento 2: Check if product has catalog rule applied to it

Tags: magento2

I'm very new to M2.

I have a block that is being added to front-end if there is no Mail In Rebate or Special Price applied to the product.

Class looks something like this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Company\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description;

class ListedPrice extends Description
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isListedPrice(): bool
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();

        if ($product->getSpecialPrice() || $product->getMailInRebate()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I add a check a product for Catalog Price rules?

We have a Group of customers that gets discounts based on Catalog Price rules and this block is being shown to them which destroys the layout.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by doing this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Company\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description;

class ListedPrice extends Description
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isListedPrice(): bool
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();

        $_price = $product->getPrice();
        $_finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();

        if (($_finalPrice < $_price) || $product->getMailInRebate()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This will cover both the Special Price and the Catalog Price Rule issues.

A post on Magento forums has given me this idea:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/How-to-get-which-catalog-price-rule-applied-on-particulate/td-p/77172

Comment: Hi Kalvin, how does the `getMnlMailInRebate` method look? I am looking for a similar solution.

Comment: @Akif its a custom method from a custom class, not Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think you wanna give a try based on [this example](https://meetanshi.com/blog/check-if-product-has-a-special-price-in-magento-2/) . Look at block method where using factory, you create a product instance and load details about that product. you could define something similar in your logic for this check.

`getMnlMailInRebate` this seems a custom method so I assume you already have something built to retrieve this data from db.

Comment: This really checks for Special Price. Special price is different from Catalog Price rule.